# Unit Test MessageListenerContainer using a mock consumer

Tags: java, kotlin, unit-testing, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Boot application with a `MessageListenerContainer` bean, which I want to unit test. How can I use a mock Kafka consumer to simulate the receipt of a number of records? I've searched and found `MockConsumer` together with examples using plain Apache Kafka, but I can't figure out how to use it with Spring Kafka's `MessageListenerContainer`. I use Kotlin and Kotest, but answers using Java/JUnit are also welcome. My unit tests don't use `@SpringBootTest`: instead, I manually create beans and dependencies in my unit tests.

My `MessageListenerContainer` configuration is like:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyKafkaConsumerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> concurrentMessageListenerContainer(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) {
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties("my-topic");
        containerProperties.setMessageListener(myMessageListener());
        return new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(
            consumerFactory,
            containerProperties
        );
    }

    @Bean
    ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = someConfiguration();
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` to have  `MessageListenerContainer` or you defining it some other way?

Comment: Do you annotate a method with `@KafkaListener` or define a bean implementing the MessageListener interface?  Then write your unit test to directly invoke that method, without setting up a mock Kafka consumer.

Comment: I second to the plain POJO method testing: no reason in extra Kafka configuration if in the end you would just verify your business method behavior.

Comment: Agreed with @ArtemBilan, you can also create consumers records manually and pass them to listeners

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. @PawełSzymczyk I'm creating my own ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer, passing my own ConsumerFactory to the constructor.

Comment: Then you can use [MockConsumerFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/mock/MockConsumerFactory.html). With that, you can get it to create a MockConsumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Therea are at least few ways to unit test processing messages from Kafka in Spring Boot. In my opinion the best option is to focus on testing business behaviour in unit tests, check application configuration with integration tests and leave testing internal Spring components to Spring team. Having that in mind you should focus on testing class implemeting `MessageListener<K, V>`  (or one of the subclasses like `AcknowledgingMessageListener<K, V>`) instead of testing `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` with `MockConsumer`, for example:

```java
    @Test
    void testMyMessageListener() {
        SomeCollaborator someCollaborator = Mockito.mock(SomeCollaborator.class);
        MessageListener<String, String> myMessageListener = new MyMessageListener(someCollaborator);
        ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord = new ConsumerRecord<>("some-topic", 0, 0, "key", "some value");

        myMessageListener.onMessage(consumerRecord);

        Mockito.verify(someCollaborator, Mockito.times(1)).someMethod();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. My message listener is not a class but a lambda parameter that calls a private function. It looks like I'll have to restructure my application.